# Get Kingston DataTraveler Locker+ working under Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, encryption, usb-drive

I have procured a 16GB Kingston DataTraveler Locker+ USB 2.0 memory stick with 256-bit AES Hardware Based Encryption.

The [official manual](http://media.kingston.com/support/downloads/DTLockerplus_userManual_A01.pdf) confirms that Linux is unsupported, but I wondered if there might be a way round this.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get this type of drive working under Ubuntu, and if so, how?

Comment: For information, oldest version of the same product had a big authentication breach: http://www.zdnet.com/article/encryption-busted-on-nist-certified-kingston-sandisk-and-verbatim-usb-flash-drives/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kingston Locker+ G3 can be accessed through linux. Here are two (non-officialy supported by Kingston) methods:

1. Using a windows virtual machine to un-lock the drive, and then releasing it to the host OS. It works for me with VMware Workstation.
2. Using the binaries shipped with another Kingston key, namely the "DataTraveler Vault Privacy 3.0". (Works under both x86 and x64 linux system.) Obviously, you would need to carry the binaries on another drive (unless you are able to edit the read-only zone of the stick).

Comment: I uses method 1 quite often. I asked Kingston support to get Linux software but get offer to exchange the key... offer that my company IT service rejected. By the way, I am interested in find the Linux binaries.

Comment: The "read-only zone" is in fact a 20 MiB ISO image stored on a flash block, and it can be written from Linux thanks to a simple "dd" command !

Comment: See also here: http://superuser.com/questions/382214/how-to-use-an-old-kingston-datatraveler-vault-privacy-usb-flash-drive-on-linux

Comment: @YvesMartin Is it possible to burn a modified ISO image with dtv30 binaries back to the sr0 device? Seems like this device is protected. Can confirm that the unlock still works in OSX High Sierra and Linux 64bit using the described method.

Comment: @ReinerRottmann I still have my now-really-old DTVP (v1)... According to this KB, an official update tool exists, so technically speaking, ISO image is replaceable: https://www.kingston.com/fr/support/technical/downloads/111289

Comment: I have just updated ISO image thanks to utility available at https://www.kingston.com/fr/support/technical/downloads/111289 but the "less-than-10mb" image does not contain Linux binaries even if included User's Guide PDF describes usage in Linux environment...

Comment: I may have found binaries from DTVP 3.0 at https://github.com/sohrberg/itsb-usb/tree/master/bin/linux64 but these fails with my old DTVP: KTGetDeviceInfo ERROR!!  return code = 0x17 . Bad luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it isn't possible to get this device working under Linux. Without the right method to decrypt, which they keep secret, there's no use really.

Formatting the drive won't do anything either, as it doesn't present itself like that to the OS.

I've got one of them here and its just simply useless to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

@duffydack Unfortunately, that won't work. The drive is set up with 2 partitions - a public partition and a private partition. The public partition contains an app that is used to access the private partition.

There is extra hardware in the memory stick that is used to access the private partition. The private partition is not a normal USB drive partition and can only be accessed using the proprietary hardware and the app on the public partition.

Not even GParted can see the private partition. It must be accessed via the app, which of course won't run under Linux.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I would wipe the stick and format with encryption.  Install the cryptsetup package.

`sudo apt-get install cryptsetup`

and if not already installed, the Disk Utility app.

`sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility`

Then use the disk utility to format to your desired filesystem type and enable encryption, like so.

[image]

Comment: Won't format it actually ...